# VBA - Internet Automation - GetElementById.Value Missing

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation, getelementbyid

Online, I see many people completing the following code to automate VBA/IE search function interactions:

```
objIE.document.getElementById("id_here").Value = "Search This Text"
```

- I receive the error "Object Required" when running this. I also lose intellisense after ObjIE.Document.

I have researched this for several hours now and would greatly appreciate any help. Here is my complete code. I will promptly provide any additional information necessary to solve this.

```
Sub InternetAutomation()

'Declaring and Setting Internet Explorer with Early Binding
Dim aExplorer As InternetExplorer
Set aExplorer = New InternetExplorer

'Set basic attributes of Internet Explorer and navigate to first webpage
With aExplorer
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "www.google.com"
End With

'Wait while Internet Explorer is busy
Do While aExplorer.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

'Search Parameters
aExplorer.Document.getElementById("1st - ib").Value = "Search This Text"

End Sub
```

Comment: The id value is "lst-ib"  , not "1st - ib"

Comment: Thanks! Still have the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me with that change to the id

Comment: Thank you very much Tim! It works for me now as well. Apparently, the "Object Required" error occurs when the id for .getElementById is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Williams alerted me to my erroneous id listed after "getElementbyID". Apparently, listing an incorrect element causes VBA to throw an "Object Required" error.

Upon correcting the element to the proper name the problem resolved.

Thanks Tim!

Any ideas on why .value doesn't show up with intellisense?

Comment: getElementById can return any matching HTML element - not just inputs. Many of the possible element type do not have a Value property...

Comment: Thank you Tim! You are incredibly helpful and kind!